# Find third value

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a very simple problem but I feel like I am brain-dead.

I cant figure it out how to calculate this in Java:

```
1321 = 0 
1771 = 640 
1500 = ?
```

Thanks.

Edit:
Sorry for no context. (And english not my first language)
I must basically calculate the value that number **1500** represents.
If **1321** is **min** (=0) and **1771** is **max** (=640) where does **1500** fall in (between **0** and **640**) ?

I hope I am more clear now :)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/what-is-wrong-in-my-proof-that-90-95-or-is-it-correct/50512#50512.

Comment: Um, what? ${}{}$

Comment: Some context would be very helpful. $1321$ is almost never $0$, and when it is, $1721$ isn't usually $640$. Are you working with modular arithmetic?

Comment: I updated my question. I hope I am more clear.

Comment: Looks like the question is about linear interpolation between data points $(1321,0)$ and $(1771,640)$,
in particular about how to find $y$ such that $(1500,y)$ would be on the same line.

The answer comes from the equation of the line passing through two known points. Have you seen that in school algebra?

Answer (score 3):

linear interpolation?

scale x ranges from 1321 to 1771
scale y you want to range from 0 to 640

gradient = (640 - 0) / (1771 -1321)

1500 -1321 = gradient ( x - 0)

x is your answer.

I'm sure you could rearrange this nicely.

(correcting typo)

Comment: i think it is $385$

Answer (score 1):

i dont know exactly if it is way to solve this problem,but i think about one thing,if $1321=0$ and  $1771=640$
then for calculating  where does fall $1500$,we have to consider what is the difference from min to $1500$ and from $1500$ to max value and make proportion.
if we do so we get
$450/179=640/x$  from this  $x=254$,i  think that we could solve this problem like this way

Comment: thanks very much for commenting on error