# Textbook on absolute continuity

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, absolute-continuity

Can someone please recommend a textbook that gives a substantial treatment of absolute continuity and is accessible (written for students; sticks to the real numbers instead of turning to more abstract generalizations)?

Comment: If you have access to interlibrary loan or ProQuest, you may want to look at Walter Eugene Klann, **Properties and Applications of Absolutely Continuous Functions**, Ed.D. Dissertation (under Donald Dale Elliott), Colorado State College [= University of Northern Colorado], 1968, ix + 190 + 1 pages. I gave a summary of its contents [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677927/bibliography-for-singular-functions), where it is bibliographic entry **[43]**.

Answer (score 2):

A way more substantial (but still accessible) treatment than the one in Royden's book can be found in Leoni's *A First Course in Sobolev Spaces*.

Answer (score 0):

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) on absolute continuity frequently uses Royden, H.L. (1988), Real Analysis (third ed.) as a reference. I think newer editions of this book are co-authored by Fitzpatrick, as Google searching the reference brought me to [this pdf](http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/books/royden-fitzpatrick/royden-fitzpatrick.pdf). See page 119 in the book numbering, page 130 in the pdf. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you can find a copy of  I. P. Natanson, Theory of functions of a real variable, I think you will be pleased with the treatment.