# When I read THEOREM 5 on p.237 in "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak, I wondered why many calculus books don't contain the following THEOREM.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question, inverse-function

I am reading "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak.

The following theorem is on p.237 in this book:

> **THEOREM 5**
> Let $f$ be a continuous one-one function defined on an interval, and suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $f^{-1}(b)$, with derivative $f^{'}(f^{-1}(b))\neq 0.$ Then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $b,$ and $$(f^{-1})^{'}(b)=\frac{1}{f^{'}(f^{-1}(b))}.$$

When I read the statement of **THEOREM 5**, I wondered why many calculus books don't contain the following **THEOREM**.
Why?

> **THEOREM**
> Let $f$ be a continuous one-one function defined on an interval, and suppose that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(f^{-1}(b)+h)-f(f^{-1}(b))}{h}=\pm\infty.$ Then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $b,$ and $$(f^{-1})^{'}(b)=0.$$

Comment: I suspect many calculus books don't have this theorem (which is new to me, and my expertise is in real analysis) is because it is too tangential and too specialized and too theoretical. Given that Spivak's book is extremely atypical for a calculus book, I'm curious why this would even be a reasonable question for "many calculus books". Indeed, the first two reasons would apply to most (undergraduate level) real analysis books, although as an exercise it would probably be appropriate in a real analysis book and it might be relevant to [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677927/13130).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you very much for your comment.