# Why does rearranging the pieces of this triangle illusion give a different area?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come 32.5 = 31.5?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287/how-come-32-5-31-5)

[image]

Comment: fairly sure there was a duplicate of this question...

Comment: There might be. That's what I thought and tried to find it (put very little effort) but couldn't.

Comment: @InterestedQuest, @Sunil This was the dupe: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287/how-come-32-5-31-5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you count carefully, you'll see that the base is meant to be $13$ units long, while the height is $5$ units long. That means that the triangle on the top on the top figure, which has a height of $2$, should have a base of length $b$, where
$$\frac{b}{2} = \frac{13}{5}$$
or $b = \frac{26}{5}$, longer than the $5$ units depicted.

Likewise, the bottom red triangle, with a base of size $8$ should have a height of length $h$, with
$$\frac{h}{8} = \frac{5}{13}$$
or $h = \frac{40}{13}$, which is a little longer than the $3$ depicted.

So in fact, the "missing square" comes from misdrawing the pictures (or from having the individual figures drawn correctly, but the composed figures not being real triangles; the two inner triangles are not similar, though they "should" be).

Answer (score 2):

Eye trick! Look at the angles formed where the red and green triangle meet.

Comment: Looking at angles may not be enough given the thick lines.  But the slope of the hypotenuse of the red triangle is $3/8 = 0.375$ while the slope for the green triangle is $2/5 = 0.4$.  If the whole thing was a triangle (which it is not) then the slope would be $5/13 =0.3846\ldots$

Comment: Indeed the thick lines are what make the "angles different" - and which is what makes it sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't true. See the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle) about this puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Take your credit card, driver's license, or some other readily available straightedge and put it against the hypotenuse. You'll find the composite shape is not a triangle, but a cleverly disguised irregular quadrilateral. The better, more mathy answers made sense once I got my brain away from the idea that there were triangles involved.

Nothing but a cheap trick designed to confound.