# Where has the extra area come from?

Tags: geometry, area

I saw this problem in the UKMT 2020 SMC

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5EJg.png]

> The diagram above shows on the left an 8 × 8 square divided into four pieces which are
> rearranged to make the 13 × 5 rectangle shown on the right.
> However 8 × 8 < 13 × 5.
> Where has the additional area come from?

I tried to do this myself, but I couldn't figure out an explanation. Maybe the figure on the right is misleading and doesn't actually form a rectangle?

Comment: [You are correct!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard_paradox)

Comment: The triangle with legs 3,8 does not align with the triangle with legs $5,5+8$ since $5/13 \ne 3/8$.

Comment: On this site the "missing square" puzzle is solved at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287/139123. This example is set up a bit differently, but it relies on the same disproportionate triangles, a right triangle with legs $5$ and $2$, a right triangle with legs $8$ and $3$, and a right triangle with legs $13$ and $5$.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/743074/6460